# How to generate custom jvm-cucumber HTML, send it through Jenkins and also ftp the json results?

Tags: java, jenkins, html-email, cucumber-jvm

How to generate custom jvm-cucumber HTML, send it through Jenkins and also ftp the JSON results? This results generation should happen after the entire mvn cucumber suite execution so that I can capture passed / failed results from the json that will be generated after test execution is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I used extended cucumber to achieve this -

Here is the extended cucumber code and create this class in your library -

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.AfterSuite;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.BeforeSuite;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;


import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

public class ExtendedCucumberRunner extends Runner {

    private Class clazz;
    private Cucumber cucumber;

    public ExtendedCucumberRunner(Class clazzValue) throws Exception {
        clazz = clazzValue;
        cucumber = new Cucumber(clazzValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Description getDescription() {
        return cucumber.getDescription();
    }

    private void runPredefinedMethods(Class annotation) throws Exception {
        if (!annotation.isAnnotation()) {
            return;
        }
        Method[] methodList = this.clazz.getMethods();
        for (Method method : methodList) {
            Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation item : annotations) {
                if (item.annotationType().equals(annotation)) {
                    method.invoke(null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        try {
            runPredefinedMethods(BeforeSuite.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cucumber.run(notifier);
        try {
            runPredefinedMethods(AfterSuite.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is runner class code that will be used to start with the mvn command and this will capture the summary based on the cucumber tags starting with @SUMMARY-

```
import libs.ExtendedCucumberRunner;
import libs.FTP;
import libs.RemoteSSH;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.reporting.CucumberResultsOverview;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.AfterSuite;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.BeforeSuite;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import static libs.BaseTest.tagCounts;
import static com.automation.steps.Common.failedCount;

@RunWith(ExtendedCucumberRunner.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "target/Destination/cucumber.json",
        overviewReport = true,
        outputFolder = "target/ext-cucumber-results"
        ,retryCount = 0)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/Destination","json:target/Destination/cucumber.json"},
        strict = true,
        monochrome = true
)

public class Runner {

    @BeforeSuite
    public static void manageResults() throws IOException {
        String directory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
        if (new File("target/Destination/cucumber.json").exists()) {
            String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("target/Destination/cucumber.json"))).toString().trim();
            if (!contents.equals("")) {
                long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
                FileUtils.copyFile(new File("target/Destination/cucumber.json"), new File("target/Destination/cucumber_" + timestamp + ".json"));
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public static void copy_json_generate_report() throws Exception {
        String directory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
        CucumberResultsOverview results = new CucumberResultsOverview();
        results.setOutputDirectory("target/ext-cucumber-results");
        results.setOutputName("cucumber-results");
        results.setSourceFile(directory+"/target/Destination/cucumber.json");
        results.execute();
        String format_tag_name="";
        if(System.getenv("TAG_NAME")==null){
            format_tag_name="Local--";
        }else {
            format_tag_name = System.getenv("TAG_NAME").
                    replaceAll("@", "").replaceAll(",", "-")
                    .replaceAll("\\[", "")
                    .replaceAll("]", "");
        }

        String destination_path = "";
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat unix_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

        if (failedCount==0) {
            destination_path ="/tmp/QA_RESULTS/"+unix_format.format(today)+"/"+format_tag_name+"_" + timestamp + ".json";
        }else{
            destination_path ="/tmp/QA_RESULTS/"+unix_format.format(today)+"/"+format_tag_name+"_" + timestamp + "--F.json";
        }
        System.out.println("After class is being run now- to copy json files!!!");

        if (new File(directory+"/target/Destination/cucumber.json").exists()) {
            System.out.println(directory+"/target/Destination/cucumber.json --exits!");
//            CommonUtils.createFile(GenerateHTMLReport(),"Destination/CucumberSummaryReport.html");
            String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(directory+"/target/Destination/cucumber.json"))).toString().trim();
            if (!contents.equals("")) {
                RemoteSSH ssh = new RemoteSSH();
                List<String> check_file_commands = Arrays.asList("mkdir -p /tmp/QA_RESULTS/"+unix_format.format(today) );
                List<String> check_file_logs = ssh.SSHClient(check_file_commands);
                String local_path = directory+"/target/Destination/cucumber.json";
                System.out.println(local_path);
                FTP ftp = new FTP();
                ftp.SCPUpload(local_path,destination_path);
            }else{
                System.out.println("File is empty!");
            }
        }
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKKILL /F /IM xxx.exe");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Killing xxxx.exe error out");
            }
    }

    public static String GenerateHTMLReport(){
        String html_string = "<!-- CSS Code: Place this code in the document's head (between the 'head' tags) -->\n" +
                "<style>\n" +
                "table.GeneratedTable {\n" +
                "  width: 100%;\n" +
                "  background-color: #ffffff;\n" +
                "  border-collapse: collapse;\n" +
                "  border-width: 2px;\n" +
                "  border-color: #ffcc00;\n" +
                "  border-style: solid;\n" +
                "  color: #000000;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n" +
                "table.GeneratedTable td, table.GeneratedTable th {\n" +
                "  border-width: 2px;\n" +
                "  border-color: #ffcc00;\n" +
                "  border-style: solid;\n" +
                "  padding: 3px;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n" +
                "table.GeneratedTable thead {\n" +
                "  background-color: #ffcc00;\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "</style>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<!-- HTML Code: Place this code in the document's body (between the 'body' tags) where the table should appear -->\n" +
                "<table class=\"GeneratedTable\">\n" +
                "  <thead>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <th>Functionality Group</th>\n" +
                "      <th>Passed</th>\n" +
                "      <th>Passed With Warning</th>\n" +
                "      <th>Failed</th>\n" +
                "      <th>Script Issue</th>\n" +
                "      <th>Env Issue</th>\n" +
                "      <th>Warning</th>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </thead>\n" +
                "  <tbody>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n";
        System.out.println(tagCounts.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String,List<Integer>> entry : tagCounts.entrySet()) {
            html_string = html_string +
                    "      <tr><td>" + entry.getKey() + "</td>\n" +
                    "      <td>" + entry.getValue().get(0) + "</td>\n" +
                    "      <td>" + entry.getValue().get(1) + "</td>\n" +
                    "      <td>" + "Script Issue Value" + "</td>\n" +
                    "      <td>" + "Env Issue Value" + "</td></tr>\n";
        }
        html_string = html_string +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "\n";
        return html_string;
    }
}
```

Now in the Jenkins configure, add the following to the content section of editable email configuration add-in-

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Pls refer the below results-</p>
<a href="${BUILD_URL}/cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html">${BUILD_URL}/cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html</a>
<p>Note: Copy and paste the above link in chrome or Firefox. The report won't work in IE.</p>
</body>
</html>
${FILE,path="target/CucumberSummaryReport.html"}
${FILE,path="target/ext-cucumber-results/cucumber-results-feature-overview.html"}
```